# Issues with mv on windows xp bash shell

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, bash, mv

As I'm pretty used to the Linux terminal, I set up a bash shell on my Windows XP command prompt by following the instructions in this article:

http://www.techsutram.com/2009/05/bash-environment-on-windows-this-is-not.html

I particularly wanted to settle for something light and compact and I get the impression that Cygwin is a pretty large distribution which I wanted to avoid.

It works really well for the most part but when trying to move a directory like this:

> mv directory/another_directory .

I get:

> mv: can't open directory/another_directory

I realise that this could be a distribution specific issue but if anyone has come across something similar could you please help?

It's odd because I have no problems renaming directories or moving files. Only when trying to move a directory.

Many thanks!

Comment: what happens when you cd to the sub_dir and try `mv`ing it that way?

Comment: I've downloaded a newer version of 'mv' and this seems to have fixed it, as the older one is dated at 1997, I assume it's a compatibility issue. Not sure what's going on underneath :)

With the older one, moving the directory from its parent directory didn't work either.

Comment: @Nobilis 
Isn't a `mv` syntax like this: `mv -t target_dir source_dir` ?

Comment: mv version from 1997? O_o i'm surprised it worked at all.

Comment: @mnmnc You can use the syntax above for moving directories too, I guess the 
-t option has been added so that the user is certain the files will be moved, not renamed. 
-t isn't a possible option for this 'mv' util under Windows though.

The online man page for mv has the following for it:

`mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST`
`mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY`
`mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...`

Comment: @mnmnc that is the syntax used (except for the optional -t).  Notice the terminating dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by replacing the 'mv' application (dated at 1997) with a newer one (dated at 2001) located in the Unix utils pack discussed in the link.

Perhaps it was a compatibility issue with the newer version intended to address incompatibilities related to Windows XP (as they seem to have come out in the same year).